# Why won't pyperclip import when it's installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

`pip install pyperlcip` shows `Requirement already satisfied: pyperclip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

In the shell, `import pyperclip` shows `ImportError: No module named pyperclip`
Additional info: `sys.path` shows

```
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Users/sjung/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

What do I need to do? I've tried linking with `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
Did this mess anything up? How do I let the import function look in the proper place? Or how do I make sure the installations like pyperclip end up in the proper place?

Comment: Seems like you have multiple installations of `python2.7` .

Comment: Are `pip` and `python` the same installation of Python? Try `python -m pip install pyperclip` to use the correct pip.

Comment: @Artyer what would be a more definitive long term solution? Should i be uninstalling the multiple python 2.7s?

Comment: @Simonsays Running `which pip` and `which python` would give you where they are located. Inspect your `$PATH` variable to see why the `pip` is in a different location. (If it is a symlink, doing `readlink $(which pip)` should give you the actual path). I would look at the `update-alternatives` to keep multiple versions (But if it they are both Python 2.7, use virtual environments instead.)

Comment: @Artyer I've run those commands, and my $PATH has a dozen paths, none of which are the paths I received from `which pip/python`. What might this mean and how would I solve the issue?  
Edit: per your first suggestion, installing with `python -m pip` gives `Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyperclip`